# Is this test statistic valid?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

There is a sample $\{(X_1,Y_1),\ldots,(X_n,Y_n)\}$ of a random variable with known distribution.
An observation $(\hat X,\hat Y)$ is obtained from $(X,Y)$ by one of two rules $R_1$ and $R_2$.
One needs to know which rule was applied more likely.
We consider a test statistic $f(\hat X,\hat Y)\in\{R_1,R_2\}$
and justify its validity by the fact that
$p((\hat X,\hat Y)| R_1)>p((\hat X,\hat Y)| R_2)$ if $f(\hat X,\hat Y)=R_1$
(similarly, $p((\hat X,\hat Y)| R_2)>p((\hat X,\hat Y)| R_1)$ if $f(\hat X,\hat Y)=R_2$).
My first question: Is this justification legitimate?

The sample $\{(X_1,Y_1),\ldots,(X_n,Y_n)\}$ is not random.
Assume that all $X_i$ belong to an interval $\Omega$.
For $\omega\in\Omega$, we have
$p((\hat X,\hat Y)|X=\omega, R_1)>p((\hat X,\hat Y)|X=\omega, R_2)$ if $f(\hat X,\hat Y)=R_1$
but these probabilities are close to 0 (or 1).
The second question: Can we still conclude that the test statistic $f$ is good?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Is $f$ chosen based on the data? And do you ask how do we make sure $f$ we chose is valid?

Comment: @tmrlvi Thanks. $f$ is the default test in a wider area of problems and I'd like to check its applicability in this particular example.

Comment: So your question is what happens if $\frac{p\left( \left(\hat{X}, \hat{Y}\right) \mid R_{1}, f\left(\hat{X}, \hat{Y}\right) = R_{1}\right)}{p\left( \left(\hat{X}, \hat{Y}\right) \mid R_{2}, f\left(\hat{X}, \hat{Y}\right) = R_{1}\right)}$ is very close to 1?

Comment: @tmrlvi No. My first question is if this fraction is less than 1 then can I conclude that $f$ is good?